# How can I convert this paypal curl to libcurl in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, curl, paypal

I am trying to use libcurl in Ubuntu instead of using system() command to communicate with PayPal. I was using system() command with curl to talk with PayPal's sandbox by PayPal REST API.

If I want to execute request token from PayPal by using libcurl in c++ (or c) code, how can I convert this curl code into libcurl code?

```
  curl https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \  
  -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
  -u "ABABABABAB:CDCDCDCDCD" \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

I found many questions about using PHP with its CURL library but not with regular c++ or c libcurl for Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself. It was very simple actually.

Here is link. http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2011-08/0043.html

Try adding "--libcurl example.c" on the end of that "curl" command 
line. Then curl will create an "example.c" file that should do 
basically the same thing. You can then edit that to neaten it up and 
add any additional functionality. 
i.e.: 
curl -k -d@/home/test/curl/login.req.xml \ 
  -H"SOAPAction:/Serv/9999/Interface/Service9999.serviceagent/portTypeEndpoint/LogInOp" 
\ 
  https://whatever.com/Serv/9999/Interface/Service9999.serviceagent/portTypeEndpoint 
\ 
  --libcurl example.c